# Join 2 Tables And Filter Sql Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have Two tables I need to total occupancy from the two tables

Table 1 **TableMaster**

```
_______________________________
|TableNo | TableType | Shared |
-------------------------------
|1       | WT        | FULL   |
|2       | WT        | FULL   |
|3       | WT        | SHARED |
|4       | WT        | SHARED |
-------------------------------
```

Table 2 **TableSharedDetails**

```
______________________________________________
|TableNo | ReservedDate | TableType | Shared |
----------------------------------------------
|4       | 29-12-2016   | WT        | FULL   |
|4       | 30-12-2016   | WT        | FULL   |
----------------------------------------------
```

My tablemaster has both full and shared table. Full table occupancy is 1 and shared table occupancy is 2 for some date we convert the shared table to full table for that I am using table 2 TableSharedDetails.

When we convert the table as full on that date i need to **increase full table + 1 and decrease shared table - 1**

Now I want the table type wise available status for particular period for example (28-12-2016 to 31-12-2016)

OUTPUT

```
______________________________________________
| ReservedDate | TableType | Shared |Totalava|
----------------------------------------------
| 28-12-2016   | WT        | FULL   |  2     |
| 28-12-2016   | WT        | Shared |  2     |
| 29-12-2016   | WT        | FULL   |  3     |
| 29-12-2016   | WT        | Shared |  1     |
| 30-12-2016   | WT        | FULL   |  3     |
| 30-12-2016   | WT        | Shared |  1     |
| 31-12-2016   | WT        | FULL   |  2     |
| 31-12-2016   | WT        | Shared |  2     |
----------------------------------------------
```

Here Totalava is count of table from tablemaster

I have tried one procedure but it is not correct

```
Create Procedure TableAvaStatus (@StartDate as DateTime, @EndDate as DateTime)
as
declare @AvaStatus table (ReserveDate DateTime, TableType varchar(10), Shared varchar(10), TotalAva int)

While @StartDate < @EndDate
Begin
    INSERT INTO @AvaStatus (ReserveDate, TableType, Shared, TotalAva)
    SELECT
        @StartDate,
        TableType,
        Shared,
        (CASE
            WHEN Shared = 'FULL' THEN COUNT(*)
            ELSE COUNT(*) END) 
        + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableSharedDetails
          WHERE Shared = 'FULL'
          AND TableType = A.TableType
          GROUP BY TableType) AS TotalAva
    FROM TableMaster A
End
Select * From @AvaStatus
```

Comment: Did you try anything to solve the problem

Comment: Yes i tried in union all but i cannot able to do that mins

Comment: Please add what ever you tried(Query) in question we will try to fix it.

Comment: ok please wait i update it

Comment: The way that it is written now, that `CASE` statement is useless as you're doing the same thing in the `'FULL'` condition as you are in the `ELSE`.

Comment: Yes but i dont know how to full table + 1 and share table - 1. please help me

Comment: Can you provide sample input data for the output you shared?

Comment: Where is the actual query producing the output? Is it in stored procedure? And desired results would be helpful. *Not correct* could mean anything.

Comment: Show corresponding (source) data for output demonstrated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming Data Type of ReservedDate is `Date`.

Try:

```
declare @startDate date
declare @endDate date

select @startDate = '2016-12-28'
select @endDate = '2016-12-31'

-- Recursive CTE to generate dates between start and end dates 
;with dateRange as
(
  select @startDate as dt  
  union all
  select dateadd(dd, 1, dt)
  from dateRange
  where dateadd(dd, 1, dt) < +dateadd(dd, 1, @endDate)
)
select  
  tbl_master.dt as ReservedDate,
  tbl_master.TableType,
  tbl_master.Shared,
  case tbl_master.shared 
    when 'FULL' then 
        tbl_master.avail+coalesce(tbl_shared.shared_count,0)
    when 'SHARED' then
       tbl_master.avail-coalesce(tbl_shared.shared_count,0)
    else 
       tbl_master.avail
   end as Totalavail

from (
  -- Join date range data with `TableMaster` to get table availablity
  select dateRange.dt,TableMaster.TableType,TableMaster.Shared,count(*) as avail
  from dateRange left join TableMaster on 1=1
  group by dateRange.dt,TableMaster.TableType,TableMaster.Shared
) as tbl_master

-- Join `TableSharedDetails` for adding and subtracting counts from table availability   
left join (
  select ReservedDate,TableType,count(*) as shared_count 
  from TableSharedDetails
  group by ReservedDate,TableType
) tbl_shared on 
tbl_master.dt=tbl_shared.ReservedDate
and tbl_master.TableType=tbl_shared.TableType;
```

SQL Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/84458/33

Explanation:

1- Use of `with dateRange` :  This is the recursive CTE used to generate dates between start and end dates provided to the stored procedure.

2- Once date range is generated ,Join range data with `TableMaster` to get the availability of tables. As there is no specific condition to join,So I put 1=1(means True in all conditions) to combine all date range data with  `TableMaster`.

3- After getting table availability , Join `TableSharedDetails` to add and subtract from FULL and shared tables data.

Comment: can u please explain this query